# Python CSV delimeter defaulting to ' '?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I'm trying to open, convert, manipulate and save a test CSV file for a larger project. So far I have opened the file, converted it to a list of lists and manipulated it. But I can't save it as a properly formatted CSV file.

At the moment, it saves, but the delimeter for each column seems to be `' '` for some unknown reason. My data set is based on sold house prices/locations/dates so whenever there is a break in the time (between the data and time), and the locations ( between the street name, town etc.) I get a new column, whereas all the other data which doesn't have any whitespace (price, id number etc.) are all put into the same column, screwing up my data.

On another note, for some odd reason my csv file keeps several empty rows between each row. I have no idea what's going on.

This is the questionable part of the code:

```
def write_new_file(lst, new_file):
'''(lst)->.CSV file
Takes a list and writes it into a .CSV file.
'''
    writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lst)
    new_file.close()
```

Here is my output in the shell:

```
>>> doc[0]

['{AACDC187-2E3E-4705-BCF3-0001C4187ADD},', '208000,', '28/06/2013 00:00,', 'AL23HX,', 'F,', 'N,', 'L,', '17,', ',', 'TENNYSON ROAD,', ',', 'ST ALBANS,', 'ST ALBANS,', 'HERTFORDSHIRE,']
```

Any help is appreciated!

edit: I've been programming for all of a couple weeks so sorry if I'm an idiot!

Edit 4:

I've changed my code to use the csv.reader function, which works great and makes it the programme a lot smaller. It looks like this now:

```
    #create an empty variable

doc= []

with open(file2, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        doc.append(row)
```

Here is my shell output:

```
    >>> doc[0]
['{AACDC187-2E3E-4705-BCF3-0001C4187ADD}', '208000', '28/06/2013 00:00', 'AL2 3HX', 'F', 'N', 'L', '17', '', 'TENNYSON ROAD', '', 'ST ALBANS', 'ST ALBANS', 'HERTFORDSHIRE', 'A']
```

But my CSV output is the same, the columns are separated according to whitespace within the strings and not according to the commas separating the list items. And there is still an empty row between rows.

My writing function is unchanged.

Final edit: Solved! calc was screwing up in the end, not Python.

Comment: Please also show the code to read the file. That is where the problem will be.

Comment: That doesn't actually open the file. What code did you use to read the file into `doc`?

Comment: You show neither what you pass as 'lst' to your function nor what `doc` is and how you built it so we can't help much. Please read this : http://sscce.org/

Comment: Added the majority of the code. Sorry I'm new to this!

Comment: You should use `csv.reader` to read the file back in, instead of rolling your own csv reader. See Erik's answer.

Comment: Just please remove the "edit 2" part—it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: Done, on both counts. I'll add up what the code looks like now, but it is still problematic!

Comment: @Scironic: `doc = list(csv.reader(...))` —no need to manually iterate over the rows and append them to a list—`csv.reader` objects are iterable (as you seem to already have discovered), so you can simply pass one to `list()` and you'll get a list containing all the rows, just like you can with any other iterable object.

Comment: Without appending them into the list I don't know how to access the data from the file in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default delimiter in the Python `csv` module for reading CSV files with `csv.reader` is comma, so if your CSV file is saved with `delimiter=','`, it should also be read in properly by default, unless you explicitly specify a wrong delimiter value.

CSV file content:

```
foo,bar,baz
hello world,again,and again
```

code:

```
>>> list(csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb')))
[['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['hello world', 'again', 'and again']]
```

as you can see, the spaces in `hello world` and `and again` are parsed properly (i.e. ignored).

To understand why your code is not working as you want it to work, you'd have to show us more of (the relevant parts of) your code.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your edit, it looks like you're using your own code to parse the CSV file—**DON'T DO THAT** (especially if you're just a beginner in programming/Python). Use the built-in `csv` module.

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        ...
    # or just rows = list(reader)
```

Furthermore, your CSV parsing code is extremely inefficient, and probably (or, well, apparently) buggy; but I didn't really go through it to try to find the bug because you can do it yourself (for learning purposes—for real code, use `csv.reader`).

A simple example of a more efficient CSV parsing code would be:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    rows = [line.split(',') for line in f]
```

...but this doesn't take into account quoting; implementing quoting support would not be as trivial and would probably invole using regular expressions or parsing code.

Comment: So I have that as my output in the shell, but not into my CSV file. and my delimeter is kept as ',' in the code above so not sure where I've gone wrong!

Comment: Thanks Erik. That really made my parsing code look much better. But the initial problem is still there, i.e. delimiting by the whitespace in strings and not by the comma in the list.

Comment: Let me get this straight: Do you need comma or space? If you need comma, how on earth are my examples/explanation insufficient? If you need space, why not just replate `delimiter=','` in my examples with `delimiter=' '`? —The point is: if you use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` with the right value for the `delimiter` paramater, you'll be fine; if you're using those 2 and still getting wrong output in the CSV, open a new question (if you still can't debug it).

Comment: Also, please make sure your input data (the data you write to the CSV in the first place) is correct to start with—because you haven't shown us your data nor the stuff the CSV file contains that you're not happy with.

Comment: I need it to be commas. I understand that by default the delimeter is ',', but whether I leave the delimeter=',' in or out, it separates my data by whitespace from within a string.

Comment: What you've said has helped to streamline my reader function, but for some reason it is still writing the data into a file wrong. I'll put up some example data from both files.

Comment: I cannot see any pasted CSV data in your question, nor can I see an example of the input data that you start out with.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help I got it all fixed now. Calc was interpreting it wrong, so python was all fine.

Comment: Although if you can tell me how to access the read file without appending the data to a list that would be great!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; if it's something non-trivial, better to ask a new question. The comments are not really meant for this. And you have too little reputation for me to take this to a chat.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I'll do some googling and ask another time if I need to. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting quotechar and qutoting also:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of the problem is in your CSV parsing code - you appear to be leaving the comma separator in the data.

When you write this to the CSV file, the CSV module is spotting that there are commas in the data, and it is quoting the data, using the single quote character, so that when you read the data back in again, it is possible to tell the difference between comma separators and commas in the data.

If you fix your reader to drop the comma separators, the problem should disappear.